# Reading a file and counting the number of lines c++

Tags: c++, file, line

Hi there im struggling to read a file and count the lines in it. I pass this code and im getting 1 more line than my file has.

```
` ifstream fin;
    
        fin.open("car.txt");
        
    // num of cars counted
    numberOffCars = 0;
    while (fin.good()) //while i have not reached the eof
    {
        getline(fin, line);
        numberOffCars++;
    }
    cout<<numberOffCars<<endl;
    fin.close();``
```

Thanks

Comment: Pop quiz: if the file is empty and has no lines in it, do you expect `fin.good()` to be true or false, immediately after opening the file?

Comment: Unrelated: Reconsider using exceptions where a simple `if` would do. `if (fin.fail()) {
cout << "file not exist!" << endl; exit(1); }` and most of the code goes away. Rule of thumb: Only use exceptions when it simplifies the flow of the code and when the behaviour is uncommon enough to really be considered exceptional

Comment: Variant of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons). In general, testing *before* doing is  wasted effort. Do, test that you did, then use the results of the doing. With test, do, use, if the do fails you used bad data.

Comment: the thing is i have 5 lines in my .txt and the numberofcars(lines) counted always is one more than the lines. Not sure why is counting an empty line at the end and how could i just get the exact number of lines

Answer (score 1):

You can check if line is empty or not by simply using [`string::empty()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/empty). Here I have used [`std::ws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/ws) to extract the leading whitespaces (if any).

**Code :**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::ifstream fin("car.txt");
    if (not fin) {
        std::cerr << "car.txt not found in working directory!";
        return -1;
    }
    std::string str;
    int n = 0;
    while (fin >> std::ws and std::getline(fin, str))
        if(not str.empty())
            ++n;
    std::cout << n;
}
```

This will ignore the empty line(s) (the ones having just whitespaces). Moreover, the main problem with your code was that you were using `getline` when `EOF` was just about to be reached. You needed to check the condition after reading the input.

Here, in my code, first `getline` will be evaluated and then `fin` (returned by `getline`) will be checked; it will tell us if last operation has succeeded or failed. In case `EOF` has been reached, it will fail, and consequently, the `while` loop will terminate.

Refer this thread for more information : [Why is `iostream::eof` inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/11613622) I would like to quote a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons#comment22561896_5605159) from it : **just because we haven't reached the EOF, doesn't mean the next read will succeed**.

Answer (score 0):

it's because your code knows "EOF" after it reads "EOF" and numberOffCars++; so result of numberOffCars is 1 more than what you expect.